# Update a list based on Input in another

Tags: list, cross-list

I have a table of jobs which i have a column to let me know whether it has been fully invoiced or not. In another table I collect a list of all the invoices raised, when the final invoice is raised a column indicating this is the final invoice is ticked. What i want to acheive is that when this box is ticked the column in the jobs list is also updated to show the job is fully invoiced.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to setup a workflow on the second list.  When the value of the row gets set to invoiced it can update the first list.

The other option is to create a custom edit form that includes some jQuery code the updates the second list.